# listing all calls to my library

Tags: c, debugging, shared-libraries, dtrace

I'm building a shared library in C, which other programs use. Sometimes, these other programs crash because of some error in my shared library. While reproducing these sort of bugs, it is very useful for me to know which functions of my library are being called, with what arguments and in what order. Of course I can add `printf()` calls to all my functions, or add breakpoints to all of them, but I figure there just has to be a better way to determine this.

Edit: since I'm doing this on OSX, **dtrace** and the related script **dapptrace** seem promising. However, after digging through some documentation I'm still a bit lost.

Say, my library is **/path/to/libmystuff.so** and I've got a program **test** which links to this library. Using **dtrace**, how would I bring up a list of all the function calls that reside in **libmystuff.so**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ltrace`](http://ltrace.org/) for that purpose if you work on a Linux system.  The original poster shows, in the comments below, a solution that works on Mac OS X using `dtrace`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this, but I'm mostly on OSX. However, the search for ltrace for osx led me to `dtrace`, which seems very promising. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: I've added the correct usage of `dtrace` to your answer as well so I can accept it.

Comment: @Rodin, do not modify other people's answers, except to clarify text, improve grammar, or reformat. If you feel additional information is needed in their answer you can supply it in a comment and recommend they add it.

Comment: For dtrace, this command does the trick: `dtrace -n 'pid$target:libmystuff::entry {}' -c ./test` If that is added to the answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I have chosen to point the readers to the solution in the comments instead of reproducing it in my answer. I hope this pleases everybody. @Rodin, thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are working on Unix.
Use `gdb` for debugging purposes.
If your program has crashed.
you can use the core file generated for looking into the stack trace.
It will give all information that you have asked for.

for more information for checking the stacktrace using gdb with the core file see [here.](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html)

Comment: will this allow me to see all calls made to my library or just the one call that leads to the crash?

Answer (score 0):

You can also log the functions call on file system with all details like function name, arguments etc.
(Usually logging is help in Server-Clients application but I am not sure about your application).
This way You can trace all calls. You can also enable logging in debugging mode only. I hope this reply will be useful to you.

Comment: can I do this without manually adding `fwrite()` calls to all of my functions?